# Preprocessor to use a different template for popup window

Tags: 7, theming

I'd like to provide the ability to open some content in a new window without all of the headers and sidebars of the normal content window.  I tried to do this with a preprocessor, and got close, but still no cigar:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {  
  if (isset($_GET['popup']) && $_GET['popup'] == '1') {
    //error_log( var_export( $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'], true ) );
    // returns as last array item: page__node__3
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__3__popup';
  }
}
```

I then have a template with the file name: page--node--3--popup.tpl.php which is just a straight copy of the region--content.tpl.php file, and it actually does hit that template!  The problem is that only the title shows up - and when I clear the cache I get a warning message that content is undefined in my popup template. I've also tried naming the file and setting the theme_hook_suggestions to 'region--content--popup'/'region_*content*_popup' with the same results.

Here is the content of region--content--popup.tpl.php

```
<div<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <div<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <a id="main-content"></a>
    <?php if ($title): ?>
    <?php if ($title_hidden): ?><div class="element-invisible"><?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <h1 class="title" id="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
    <?php if ($title_hidden): ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($tabs): ?><div class="tabs clearfix"><?php print render($tabs); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($action_links): ?><ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul><?php endif; ?>
    <?php print $content; ?>
    <?php if ($feed_icons): ?><div class="feed-icon clearfix"><?php print $feed_icons; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

The H1 page title appears and nothing else.

Comment: Can you put the content of page__node__3_popup?

Comment: question updated with content of the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

print render($page['content']);

You can find the variables available to you in the template by printing get_defined_vars() using print_r(), core's debug() function, or one of the extremely handy devel module debugging functions such as kpr() or dpm().

I'd install devel and do this:

kpr(get_defined_vars());

Your modal method might not play nicely with page cache so I'd definitely test to make sure it fits your usecase.

Comment: Thank you, using $page['content'] did the trick.  The mystery to me is when $content is populated and when it's not.  Thanks for the pointers for debug options.  Ignorant of the 'drupal way', I've been using good old error_log(var_export($arg,true)).